# How to map Multiple dispatch actions to single prop in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to dispatch two actions when submit button is pressed.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onSubmitPressed: countryCode => dispatch(createCountry(countryCode)),
    onSubmitPressed: countryCode => dispatch(loadCountry(countryCode)),
});
```

The above code works but gives a warning

> Duplicate key 'onSubmitPressed'

How to modify the code to map both dispatch actions to single prop without duplicating the key.

Comment: Does `createCountry(countryCode)` return a function (thunk action)?

Comment: @HMR loadCountry is a thunk. createCountry is an action creator.

Comment: I see, then you can do: `const mapDispatchToProps = {
  onSubmitPressed: (countryCode) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(createCountry(countryCode));
    return dispatch(loadCountry(countryCode));
  },
};` but if createCountry would be a thunk that returned the promise and you can only load it after it's created then you have to do: `const mapDispatchToProps = {
  onSubmitPressed: (countryCode) => (dispatch) =>
    dispatch(createCountry(countryCode)).then(() =>
      dispatch(loadCountry(countryCode))
    ),
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onSubmitPressed: countryCode => {
      dispatch(createCountry(countryCode));
      dispatch(loadCountry(countryCode));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best way to do this but if you need it that way I think that might do the trick:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onSubmitPressed: (countryCode) => {
        dispatch(createCountry(countryCode));
       dispatch(loadCountry(countryCode));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely not sure about this, but it probably works

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onSubmitPressed: countryCode => {
        dispatch(createCountry(countryCode));
        dispatch(loadCountry(countryCode));
    }
});
```